# Dump terminal session to file?

Tags: linux, terminal

I run gnome-terminal with unlimited scroll-line history
I want to dump text I can see in terminal to file and parse it

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the whole contents of the terminal history:

In the gnome-terminal menu, **Edit > Select All** and then **Edit > Copy**. (Or use your favorite keyboard shortcut for the copy.)

Then paste anywhere.

If you want just part of the history, select with your mouse and then copy.

Comment: Yeah, I know but the scrollback is long and that's why I asked this question

Comment: @zetah: Use Edit -> Select All. Done.

Comment: I don't have a Select All option in my terminal (Linux Red Hat)

Comment: Imray: Are you using gnome-terminal, or a different terminal emulator? (I don't know what Red Hat's default is.) The original question here was about gnome-terminal. If gnome-terminal, what version? (I.e., what does `gnome-terminal --version` say?)

Comment: this everybody knows. Is there any way to make it permanent by making changes in any settings which will dump all the terminal contents to a user specified file so that we can avoid this manual copy paste thing every time?

Comment: @sree: The original asker didn't know it!  This is the answer to their question.

Comment: @sree: I don't know an answer to your question.  I recommend you ask it as a question of its own.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the unix [script](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script) command to capture things as you go.

Comment: This is a great command, but it doesn't answer the question, which asks about dumping some text already visible in the terminal.

Comment: Can any of this tools capture what's already on screen, or I need to start it before? I mean all this current text have to be somewhere in memory and able to extract perhaps?

Comment: Sadly, script needs to be started in advance. It captures everything "visible" in the terminal - so things like passwords do not appear usually.

Comment: This is a beautiful command, thanks a lot. The typescript file opens with control characters, how do I escape these characters?

Comment: could you please update link for a script ? or preferably write script here ?site in a link is not reachable anymore

Answer (score 4):

If it's the output of a program that you want to capture and parse, simply redirect (`>`) it into a file

```
program_with_lots_of_output > output.log
```

and then parse it. Append a `2>&1` to that if you want standard error as well.

If you want a screen capture (i.e. including input), use the [script](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) program.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the 'tee' command. Tee bifurcates out stdout and makes a copy out the output in a file. So you can see the output and have the output stored also. Example:

ls | tee ls_out