# How to save terminal output automatically in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I was wondering if there's any possible way to save the output of a shell script while to a file while it's running in terminal. for example, say I'm compiling a java program with the command `javac foo.java`. How would I save all the output of that particular command (errors, etc.) to a file for future reference without having to hit `command- s` and select save and replace after every time I run the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `javac foo.java > output.txt` to capture the output of your command to the file `output.txt`.

This will however hide all output from you while it is compiling your module.

If you would like to see the output of your build in the terminal *and* at the same time capture the output into file `output.txt` you can use `tee`:

```
javac foo.java | tee output.txt
```

The `tee` program reads from stdin and writes everything into the specified file and also to stdout again.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want ?

```
javac foo.java > output.txt
```

All error will go in the output.txt and nothing will print on the shell.

Answer (score 1):

I use tee

javac foo.java | tee output.log

similar to this thread.

[Dump terminal session to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564960/dump-terminal-session-to-file)